# When is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt n]$ a Euclidean Domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-domain

Is there a complete classification of all the known integer values of $n$ such that the title holds? The obvious ones are if $n$ is a perfect square, either positive or negative, which includes $\pm 1$, as well as the values $n=\pm 2$. From there, I know that all other values of n are positive. From what I've seen, for square free n, it has to be either a prime congruent to 3 mod 4, or it has to have only such primes and 2 in its prime factorization, such as 14 or 22 for example, but it isn't true for all such numbers. I've been told that it is conjectured that there are only finitely many square free integers n such that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt n]$ is a Euclidean Domain, but I can't find much information about that.

Are there any primes congruent to 3 mod 4 or products of such that are known to not fit this requirement, or is it simply that it hasn't been proven yet? What is the least number n for which the classification of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt n]$ is unknown?

Comment: No, it does not. But this does: https://oeis.org/A048981 (at least for "Euclidean domain for the [field norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm)).

Comment: What doesn't? I don't understand. Aren't there only finitely many known values? Then there must be a simple classification of them.

Comment: My "No, it does not" was an answer to lulu's now self-deleted comment, which asked whether [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016671) answered your question. My link to OEIS gave the (finite) list of the squarefree integers $d$ for which $O(\Bbb Q(\sqrt d))$ is Euclidean for the field norm. There are no other (squarefree) negative $d$'s for which it admits an Euclidean norm, but it is conjectured that there are infinitely many such positive $d$'s. For more details and references, see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anneau_euclidien#Autres_anneaux_euclidiens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n$ negative this is relatively easy - the only such $n$ are $-1,-2$. For other negative $n$, this ring is not a UFD: $2$ is irreducible (since there are no elements of norm $2$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{n}]$) and divides either $\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{n}$ or $(1+\sqrt{n})(1-\sqrt{n})$, but doesn't divide either factor. Note that for $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ this is sometimes remedied by working in the full ring of integers of the quadratic field (which is $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2}]$ for $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ squarefree), which is a UFD or Euclidean for a handful more values of $n$.

For positive $n$, the situation is very complicated. It is conjectured that then $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{n}]$ is a Euclidean domain iff it is a UFD, and when the latter holds is somewhat more understood, so let me focus on that.

Firstly, in order for it to be a UFD, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{n}]$ has to be the full ring of integers in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{n})$. Unless $n$ is a square, this forces $n$ to be squarefree and congruent to either $2$ or $3\bmod 4$. Further, we can restrict the number of prime factors $n$ can have - it follows from Gauss's genus theory that the $2$-torsion in the narrow class group has order $2^{\omega(n)-1}$, and hence that of the class group is at least $2^{\omega(n)-2}$. Furthermore, if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ then the two are equal (since $a^2-nb^2=-1$ has no solution). Since for these rings being a UFD is equivalent to having trivial class group, this means $\omega(n)\leq 2$ if $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$ and $\omega(n)=1$ otherwise. Hence $n$ is either a prime $3\pmod 4$, or twice an odd prime. Both of these cases occur, as indicated for instance by $n=3,6$. Those specific $n$ are also known to give (norm-)Euclidean domains. If we were to consider full rings of integers, then some products of two odd primes would also appear, but that's it.

Unfortunately, this is about where our knowledge ends. It is conjectured that there are infinitely many values of $n$ for which these rings are UFDs and EDs, and in fact it is expected that this holds for a majority of prime values of $n$, but this is far from known. You can find some list of known values on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003172) (ignoring cases $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$, as then your ring is not the ring of integers).

As for the least unknown cases - this is the sort of problem where (with current knowledge, thanks to [Harper's work](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/is-euclidean/A20F443C0FDB4E3935DC1402C1060D74)) the problem is essentially reduced to a computational problem, so it is hard to pin down what is the least unknown case. Harper himself checked this in his PhD thesis when $4n\leq 500$ (and indeed all UFDs are EDs in this range), but I have no idea if and how far this has been pushed since 2004.

Edit: I have found a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/functiones-et-approximatio-commentarii-mathematici/volume-37/issue-2/Euclidean-algorithm-in-small-Abelian-fields/10.7169/facm/1229619657.full?tab=ArticleLink) of Narkiewicz which proves that for real quadratic fields, the "UFD implies ED" holds with at most two exceptions.

Comment: Did you really mean  $(1+\sqrt{-n})(1-\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: You said that n has to either be a prime congruent to 3 mod 4, or the double of one or 2. I'm just making sure I got that right. The product of an even number of integers congruent to 3 mod 4 is itself always congruent to 1 mod 4, so it is immediately disqualified. Then does that mean that, for example, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{231}]$ can't be a UFD as 231 = 3*7*11?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Typo, fixed.

Comment: @BorisDimitrov That's correct. In the algebraic number theory terms, $231$ having more than two prime factors implies that its class number is even, but being a UFD is equivalent to having class number equal to 1.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you wrote $n\leq 125$ as $4n\leq 500$?

Comment: @BorisDimitrov:  perhaps because $4n$ is the [discriminant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341560/information-about-the-discriminant-given-a-quadratic-extension-of-fields)

Comment: J.W.Tanner is right. Harper has verified this assertion for quadratic fields of discriminant $\leq 500$, and the discriminant of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{n})$ is $4n$ for $n$ squarefree and $2$ or $3\pmod4$.